# Surface Area of the top half of an Astroid

Tags: integration, surfaces

[image]

How would I go about beginning this question? I have applied the standard surface area integral formula but it becomes complicated quickly.

Comment: What have your written down so far for the surface area integral?

Comment: S = 2pi * integral(f(x)sqrt(1+(dy/dx)^2). I'm using this as my f(x): y = +(sqrt(a^(2/3) - y^(2/3)))^3. Sorry, I don't know how to add it in math format.

Comment: Yes, so be brave and calculate out the integrand. When you do, you'll get an integral that looks horrible for a moment. And then you'll see an obvious substitution that makes it easy.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we use the parametrization $x=a\cos^3\theta, y=a\sin^3\theta, \;0\le\theta\le\pi$ and symmetry, we have

$\displaystyle S=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\pi(a\sin^3\theta)\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2}\;d\theta=4\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(a\sin^3\theta)(3a\sin\theta\cos\theta) d\theta$

$=\displaystyle 12\pi a^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^4\theta\cos\theta\;d\theta=12\pi a^2\int_0^1u^4\;du=12\pi a^2\left[\frac{1}{5}u^5\right]_0^1=\frac{12\pi a^2}{5}.$